# HTTPS request hangs indefinitely

Tags: ssl, https

Basically I need to use HTTPS to authenticate an API, but the problem is that when I try to use it the process hangs. For instance, if I use:

```
curl http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

I get an answer, but if a try this:

```
curl https://www.stackoverflow.com
```

I get any response and output.

If I pass the -verbose flag I get the follow response

> - Rebuilt URL to: https://www.stackoverflow.com
> - Trying 216.58.202.4...
> - Connected to www.google.com (216.58.202.4) port 443 (#0)
> - found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
> - found 592 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
> - ALPN, offering http/1.1

I trying this in a virtual machine, hosted in a server that I am accessing through ssh.

Any advice?

Comment: Interestingly enough I found another user with this same question - were you able to solve your problem and if not can you add --trace-ascii so we can compare the issues?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. Where `HTTP` works fine but it hangs at `HTTPS` in my HTTP server.

And my problem is I did not install the certificate properly.

Comment: I have the same issue, it hangs at HTTPS, but what was the problem with the certificate installation ?